# Autcropping pictures

Tags: html, image, blogs

Users can post messages on a blog. They also can use pictures.

I want the pictures to be auto-cropped (into a certain height, width and certain position) when they post it as a comment. I can fully access and change the HTML code, but since every image has a different name every attempt has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Every image may  have a different name but they all can be called by "image"(All are images)

As for  resizing  the images this can be done through javascript....

```
image.style.width = '10%'
image.style.height = '50%'
```

or throught css...

```
image{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you give me more information about the javascript please?